# I am extracting text from image with python using Tesseract OCR. But the program is quite slow, how can I optimize it?

Tags: python, optimization, ocr, python-tesseract

I am writing a python code that extracts the text from the image using tesseract. But it takes me about 2.5 seconds to extract the texts from each image. What can I do to speed up this program? How can I optimize the Tesseract OCR code and increase the working speed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpKWF.png) Here is my extract code that I wrote.

In the program I wrote, I extract the texts from the pictures in a folder with about 20 screenshots and save them as a .txt file. While this process should take under 1 second for each picture, it takes about 2.5-3 seconds. This is not good for me. Is there a way to optimize this program? How Tesseract OCR works faster.

Comment: "The time it takes for me is less than 1 second per image" so what is this process? if it is so quick, then use that.

Comment: Translation error sorry. I need less than 1 second.

Comment: the 2.5 secs are not just text extraction time, it also includes opening the txt file and saving the text into it!

Comment: So can I shorten it?

Comment: the extration time depends on the image quality!if you can enhace it, may be.

Comment: If the goal is to reduce the total runtime of the program, you could use the Python multiprocessing library to run the 20 extractions in parallel.

Comment: So can you suggest a documentation or resource so I can adapt this to my own code?

Comment: You should write your code in the question using ``` before and after the code. Then, delete the screenshot.